# Publishing error with Sitecore 8.2 Update 3 and Solr 6.1

Tags: publishing

We are getting below error when publishing content for the first time to web database after Sitecore upgrade. The publishing method is `publish site -> republish /smart publish`.

> Job started: Publish to 'web'|#Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentException: The supplied DateTime represents an invalid time.  For example, when the clock is adjusted forward, any time in the period that is skipped is invalid.
>   Parameter name: dateTime
>      at System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime dateTime, TimeZoneInfo sourceTimeZone, TimeZoneInfo destinationTimeZone, TimeZoneInfoOptions flags, CachedData cachedData)
>      at Sitecore.DateUtil.ToUniversalTime(DateTime serverTime)
>      at Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemPublishing.GetDate(ID fieldId, DateTime defaultValue)
>      at Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemPublishing.get_ValidFrom()
>      at Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemPublishing.InValidRange(DateTime date)
>      at Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemPublishing.IsValid(DateTime date, Boolean requireApproved, Database targetDatabase)
>      at Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemPublishing.GetValidVersion(DateTime date, Boolean requireApproved, Boolean allowEmpty, Database targetDatabase)
>      at Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemPublishing.GetValidVersion(DateTime date, Boolean requireApproved, Database targetDatabase)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.DetermineAction.Process(PublishItemContext context)
>      at (Object , Object[] )
>      at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
>      at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.PublishItemPipeline.Run(PublishItemContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate entry, PublishContext context, List`1& referrers, List`1& children)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate entry, PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1 entries, PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate entry, PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1 entries, PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate entry, PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1 entries, PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate entry, PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1 entries, PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate entry, PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1 entries, PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate entry, PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1 entries, PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate entry, PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1 entries, PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate entry, PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1 entries, PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.Process(PublishContext context)
>      at (Object , Object[] )
>      at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
>      at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.PublishPipeline.Run(PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Publisher.PublishWithResult()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
>      at Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args)
>      at (Object , Object[] )
>      at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
>      at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
>      at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)

Has anyone come across this error? Please advice.

Comment: Does the time of the server correct? Can you check if the item date statistics are in the future and also the server time if it is corresponding to the Sitecore instance

Comment: @HishaamNamooya - all sitecore components including database, solr service are on the same machine.

Comment: are they in Cloud ? i.e. would have been deployed into new timezone. Also need to understand when was your last successful publish datetime. GMT +/- ?

Comment: Can you check from the ShowConfig.aspx page if you have specified a timezone. The setting name is `ServerTimeZone`

Comment: @HishaamNamooya ServerTimeZone has default blank value. Sitecore should be using the operating system time zone

Comment: this seems Daylight Saving Time adjustment triggered this issue. :)

Comment: Database backup was taken from UTC timed server and restored onto local machine with EST timezone. So, setting ServerTimeZone to "UTC" allowed the publishing to finish successfully.

Comment: So, setting `web.config` value of `ServerTimeZone` to `UTC` allowed the publishing to finish successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I witnessed very similar behavior, not during publishing, but when setting item restrictions. Upon item save, the same exception was witnessed.

The issue in our case was that a content author attempted to stage an item within the timespan of daylight savings time. This happened in Spring when clocks are moved forward an hour.

The user staged a version to be unpublished at 2:00 AM on Sunday, March 8th, 2020. The server is in the EST time zone and the `ServerTimeZone` setting is blank.

The solution was to choose a time outside of the 2:00 AM to 3:00 AM range where daylight savings kicks in.

Conversely, in November when clocks are set backward an hour, the issue is likely a bit different- where content could become published at e.g. 1:30am, then unpublished when clocks are set back to 1:00am, then republished again at 1:30am. Though this is dependent on how autopublish settings are set up and start/end times for restrictions.